# Difficulty using seperate template files in ember router with browserify

Tags: node.js, ember.js, browserify

I've followed this tutorial http://kroltech.com/2013/12/boilerplate-web-app-using-backbone-js-expressjs-node-js-mongodb/ to set up my backend node.js server, but instead of using backbone-marionette for the frontend I want to try ember. Therefore, having successfully set up the server, I am now going through this tutorial for ember http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/.

The problem I'm running into is including external templates into my ember routes. With this code and the todos template written in the browser the app works fine.

```
var Ember = require('ember');

window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();

Todos.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('todos', { path: '/' });
});
```

However, with a template written in ./templates/application.hbs and using browserify to try this,

```
Todos.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource(require('./templates/application.hbs'), { path: '/' });
});
```

I get the errors shown below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function myapp.js:46841
Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/' did not match any routes in your application
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:12978:19)
    at Object.Ember.assert (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:12141:11)
    at http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:47347:15
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:22081:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:21751:9)
    at publishRejection (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:22179:7)
    at http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:30448:7
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:18195:24)
    at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:3300/js/myapp.js:18283:27) myapp.js:15589
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/' did not match any routes in your application
```

I was hoping someone could shed some light on how to include external templates in an ember router. Thanks!

Comment: The first parameter that's passed into the resource method is a resource name.  Inserting the template into the page can happen well before this point, or at least before the template is built.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into it! I think I did a poor job explaining my question - I understood that it was the template name but I didn't understand how to include that in my application. I searched around a bit more and found `grunt-ember-templates`.

For future reference, they have really good docs to get you set up, this is what my emberTemplates code looked like.

```
emberTemplates: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                templateBasePath: 'client/src/templates'
            },
            files: {
                'build/templates.js': ['client/src/templates/*.hbs']
            }
        }
    },
```

And then I just added `'application'` as my route template name.
Don't forget to compile all of build/ in your app build.